# XSLT:Use of concat function

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to display only limited characters in html td tag,following is my code,
 if "VAR1" has less than 10 character,it's displaying '...' directly,how to check this out???

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(VAR1,1,10),'...')"/></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only show 10 characters, but only show the ... when there are more than 10 characters in the original string, you could do this in a single expression live so

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
   substring(VAR1,1,10), 
   substring('...', 1 div (string-length(VAR1) &gt; 10)))"/>
```

So, when **VAR1** is '123456789' it will output just this

```
123456789
```

But when **VAR1** is '123456789012' it will output this

```
1234567890...
```

To explain how this works, the following expression will either be true or false, depending on whether the length of the string is more than 10 or not

```
(string-length(VAR1) &gt; 10)
```

When used in a numeric expression, true evaluates to 1, and false evaluates to 0. Now, in the case of the string being more than 10 characters in length, the full expression is evaluated like so

```
substring('...', 1 div (string-length(VAR1) &gt; 10)))
   = substring('...', 1 div true)
   = substring('...', 1 div 1)
   = substring('...', 1)
   = '...'
```

So, with more than 10 characters, you get the '...' at the end.

However, when you have less than 10 characters, it evaluates like so

```
substring('...', 1 div (string-length(VAR1) &gt; 10)))
   = substring('...', 1 div false)
   = substring('...', 1 div 0)
   = substring('...', (A very big number!))
   = ''
```

So, with less than 10 characters, the substring does not return anything.

Comment: Tim:In the above answer,"substring('...', 1 div (string-length(VAR1) > 10))" the syntax of the code here is wrong it seems.Could you please correct it.

Comment: You will need to say why it is wrong, as it works OK for me. Thanks!

Comment: Tim:The second substring`s syntax seems incorrect,check out "substring('...', 1 div (string-length(VAR1) > 10))".If it`s correct please tell me how it works.I`m now trying this in VBScript.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to explain in more detail what is going on.

Comment: Tim:Thanks a lot for the explanation.But i`m trying to use the same in VBScript,it saying like "Microsoft VBScript compilation (0x800A03EE)Expected ')'".And i`ve replaced '...' with "...".

Answer (score 0):

if "VAR1" has less than 10 character,it should display '...' ? if this is your question, the following is the answer

```
<td>
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test='string-length(VAR1) &gt; 10'>
     <xsl:value-of select=concat(substring(VAR1,1,10),'...')/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="VAR1"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</td>
```